# IIS settings problem

Tags: .net, html, iis, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have installed IIS on my windows7 but it is some problems with it. I successfully can open html files like (http)://localhost/index.html , but can't open ASP site: (http)://localhost/ProjectList.aspx

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

What the problem?
(I have already reinstalled .NET 4.0)

Maybe it is another way to wath my website? Like with the help of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the windows feature for IIS are switched on to allow .net

if on winodws 7 then click

start -> control panel -> programs -> turn windows features on or off - > Internet Information Services make sure the following options are switched on

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` ?